# Hibernate flush/commit collection owner not associated with session

Tags: java, database, hibernate

In our code we have a many to many relation, where the relation table also contains a few additonal fields.

For example:
We have Trip with resources where a trip can have multiple equipments and equipment can be reused. When the equipment is not used anymore it is removed. So we have the following objects:

- Trip
- Equipment (Equipment also contains another list with data, I'll call it wheels)
- TripEquipmentRelation

When replacing equipment on a trip we first

- remove the relation between Equipment and TripEquipmentRelation
- remove the relation between Trip and TripEquipmentRelation
- remove the TripEquipmentRelation
- Because the equipment is not used anymore we also remove the equipment itself.
- Add new equipment to a trip.

Add this point we do a manual flush on the session because we need the generate id's from the new objects. So far so good. But when the applicationServer tries to commit the session we get the following error:

```
AssertionFail E org.hibernate.AssertionFailure <init> an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session)
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: collection owner not associated with session Equipment.wheels
at org.hibernate.engine.Collections.processDereferencedCollection(Collections.java:88)
at org.hibernate.engine.Collections.processUnreachableCollection(Collections.java:39)
```

Even when the wheels collection is empty.

When removing the flush the save action is succesfull. Could someone explain to me why flushing the session manually is not working?

Thx in advance

Comment: I guess if you refresh the equipment (or parent of it) entity before adding wheels - (before flushing), then even flush should work. Save will treat the entire tree as new and would save. Flush would look for saving new changes. So the object needs to be in a 'managed' condition. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reaction. Strange thing is that the exception is thrown on the removed equipment not on the one that's added. And wheels are not there on both the new situation as the old situation. But I'll try refreshing the parent object after the removal of the object. I'll let you know

Comment: Refreshing the Trip before adding the new equipment doesn't seem to fix my problem. It results in a StaleObjectException.